# CI controller function returns wrong count when displaying all records

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

When i select all from dropdown to display all records it's showing wrong count like: (Showing 1 to 293 of 288 entries)

I'm confused where i'm lacking.

Table view:

```
 <table id="measuretable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!-- <th width="5%">id</th> -->
            <th>Measure</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Ready</th>
            <th>Memo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!-- <th><input type="hidden" class="form-control column-search" data-column="0"></th> -->
            <th><input type="text" class="form-control column-search" data-column="0"></th>
            <th><input type="text" class="form-control column-search" data-column="1"></th>
            <th><input type="hidden" class="form-control column-search" data-column="2"></th>
            <th><input type="text" class="form-control column-search" data-column="3"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Script:

```
var table = $('#measuretable').DataTable({

    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "paging": true,
    "orderable": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo base_url('user/getMeasuresData'); ?>",
        "type": "GET"
    },
    "columns": [{
            "data": "0"
        },
        {
            "data": "1"
        },
        {
            "data": "2"
        },
        {
            "data": "3"
        },
    ]
});

$('#measuretable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var row = table.row(this).data();
    if (row) {
        window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('user/editMeasure/'); ?>" + row.DT_RowId;
    }
});

$('#measuretable tbody').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});

$('.column-search').on('keyup', function() {
    var column = table.column($(this).data('column'));
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().trim();
    if (searchTerm === '') {
        column.search('').draw();
    } else {
        column.search(searchTerm).draw();
    }
});

$('#measuretable tbody').on('click', '.row-clickable', function() {
    var id = $(this).find('td:first-child').text();
    window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url('user/editMeasure/'); ?>' + id;
});
```

Controller function:

```
 public function getMeasuresData()
    {
        $data = $this->measure->getMeasureList($this->input->get());
        $rowCount = $data['recordsTotal'];
        $output = array(
            "sEcho" => intval($this->input->get('sEcho')),
            "iTotalRecords" => $rowCount,
            "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $rowCount,
            "aaData" => []
        );
        $i = $this->input->get('iDisplayStart') + 1;

        foreach ($data['data'] as $val) {

            $output['aaData'][] = array(
                "DT_RowId" => $val['0'],
                $val['0'],
                $val['1'],
                ($val['2'] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No'),
                $val['3'], 
            );
        }

        echo json_encode($output);
        die;
    }
```

model function:

```
 public function getMeasureList($params = array())
    {
        $start = isset($params['start']) ? intval($params['start']) : 0;
        $limit = isset($params['length']) ? intval($params['length']) : 10;
    
        $columns = array(
            0 => 'id',
            1 => 'short_name',
            2 => 'full_name',
            3 => 'ready',
            4 => 'memo'
        );
    
        $order_by = "id";
        $dir = 'DESC';
        $order = 'id';
    
        if (isset($params['start'])) {
            $start = intval($params['start']);
        }
    
        if (isset($params['length'])) {
            $limit = intval($params['length']);
        }
    
        if (isset($params['order'][0]['column'])) {
            $index = $params['order'][0]['column'];
            $order = $params['order'][0]['dir'] === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';
            $order_by = $columns[$index];
        }
    
        $this->db->select('m.id,m.short_name,m.full_name,m.ready,p.memo')
            ->join('publication_assignments p', 'p.measure_id = m.id', 'left')
            ->distinct('m.id');

        if ($limit != -1) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        }
        $this->db->order_by($order_by, $dir);
    
        $result = $this->db->get('measures m')->result_array();
    
        $totalRecords = $this->db->select('count(*) as allcount')->from('measures')->count_all_results();
    
        $totalFiltered = $totalRecords;
        
        foreach ($params['columns'] as $key => $value) {
            
            if (isset($value['search']['value']) && $value['search']['value'] != "") {    
                $words = $value['search']['value'];
                
                $this->db->reset_query();

                if($key == 0)
                {
                    $this->db->select('m.id,m.short_name,m.full_name,m.ready,p.memo')
                            ->join('publication_assignments p', 'p.measure_id = m.id', 'left')
                            ->distinct('m.id')
                            ->like('m.short_name', $words);
                    
                    $result = $this->db->get('measures m')->result_array();
                }
                if($key == 1)
                {
                    $this->db->select('m.id,m.short_name,m.full_name,m.ready,p.memo')
                                ->join('publication_assignments p', 'p.measure_id = m.id', 'left')
                                ->distinct('m.id')
                                ->like('m.full_name', $words);
            
                    $result = $this->db->get('measures m')->result_array();
                }
                if($key == 3)
                {
                    $this->db->select('m.id,m.short_name,m.full_name,m.ready,p.memo')
                                ->join('publication_assignments p', 'p.measure_id = m.id', 'left')
                                ->distinct('m.id')
                                ->like('p.memo', $words);
            
                    $result = $this->db->get('measures m')->result_array();
                }
            }
        }
    
        $data = array();
    
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $nestedData = array();
            // $nestedData[] = $row["id"];
            $nestedData[] = $row["short_name"];
            $nestedData[] = $row["full_name"];
            $nestedData[] = $row["ready"];
            $nestedData[] = $row["memo"];
            $data[] = $nestedData;
        }

        $json_data = array(
            "recordsTotal" => intval($totalRecords),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
            "data" => $data
        );
    
        return $json_data;
    }
```

i tried
`if ($limit != -1) {     $this->db->limit($limit, $start); }`

but nothing happens

Can anyone explain me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a problem with your joins, try dump generated queries and reply them manually on DB, it could help..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).